# HDL - PC.hdl but starting off with x2 8 bit registers

Tags: hdl, nand2tetris

So, I basically need to create a PC.hdl, but starting off with x2 8 bit registers. Here's the starting point:

```
// This file is BASED ON part of www.nand2tetris.org
// and the book "The Elements of Computing Systems"
// by Nisan and Schocken, MIT Press.
// File name: project03starter/a/PC.hdl

/**
 * A 16-bit counter with load and reset control bits.
 * if      (reset[t] == 1) out[t+1] = 0
 * else if (load[t] == 1)  out[t+1] = in[t]
 * else if (inc[t] == 1)   out[t+1] = out[t] + 1  (integer addition)
 * else                    out[t+1] = out[t]
 */

CHIP PC {
    IN in[16],load,inc,reset;
    OUT out[16];

    PARTS:
    // Something to start you off: you need *two* 8-bit registers
    Register(in=nextLow,  out=out[0..7],  out=currentLow,  load=true);
    Register(in=nextHigh, out=out[8..15], out=currentHigh, load=true);

    // Handling 'inc' to increment the 16-bit value also gets tricky
    // ... this might be useful
    And(a=inc, b=lowIsMax, out=incAndLowIsMax);
    // ...

    // The rest of your code goes here...
}
```

I know how to do this normally with just handling the 16 bit but I'm not sure how to go about this with 8 bit registers.

Could anyone please help me with the correct solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever reach a solution to this problem, or would you be able to give any advice for someone struggling to solve this same issue?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an 8-bit adder, you can implement a 16-bit incrementer using 2 adders, one of which computes currentLow+1, and the other which computes currentHigh+(carry output of the low bits adder)

Comment: Thank you. Could you help me with the code for this implementation please? I do have an 'Add8' chip.

Comment: I am especially unsure on how to do integer addition like 'currentLow+1' in this HDL language.

Comment: The point of Stackoverflow isn't to do your homework for you, but to help you understand what you need to know in order to do your homework. If you have an 8 bit adder, you can make it an incrementer by making one of the inputs a fixed value of 00000001. Once you figure out how to do that, the other 8 bits should be easy.

That said, an incrementer is a very special case of addition. I recommend you look back to a previous lesson where you learned about the half-adder, and consider how that functional unit might be hooked up to provide a circuit that just adds one to the input.